# jquery.js and bootstrap.js collision occur in server

Tags: php, jquery, yii, cgridview

i have implemented my project in Yii. i have issue with CGrid view search panel. it working fine in localhost. but it not working in server. i found that issue, but i do not know how to overcome these issue.

i found issue ie Jquery 2.0.3.js and assests bootstrap js. its collision occur so that server side its not working properly:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'mygridview',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'recipeType_name',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn','template'=>'{update}{delete}',
    ),
),  )); ?>
```

Comment: If you want help, we need to know what collision you found, what error you get, and other info you think might be usefull.

Comment: it occur based on server issue. we are using server is Nginx. but localhost is apace server. in localhost its working fine all process